# Why is Bat-sheva called Bat-shua?

Tags: names, tanach

Why is [Bat-sheva bat Eliam](https://www.sefaria.org.il/II_Samuel.11?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi) called Bat-shua bat Amiel in [Divrei Hayamim 1:3:5](https://www.sefaria.org.il/I_Chronicles.3.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)?

The commentaries Sefaria brings merely state that the names (both Bat-sheva/Bat-shua and Eliam/Amiel) are interchangeable, but what's the reason for the name change?

---

Note: I'm aware that this can be asked about several other people in Tanach who have name changes. I'm wondering specifically about Bat-sheva.

Comment: I'm not holding but searching Otzar HaChochmah shows me that Seder HaDoros, seemingly quoting the Rema MiPano, understands that Yehudah's wife Bas Shua is Bas Sheva. I think he means Bas Sheva is a gilgul of Yehuda's wife. He says that the same scandal that happened with Dovid and Bas Sheva happened with Yehuda and Tamar. Not really following...but I guess this is all learned out from your verse.

Comment: Why assume gilgul? Perhaps there was a story akin to Poe's The Spectacles? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Spectacles_(short_story)

Comment: @robev interesting direction. Yes, Seder Ha'dorot is filled with interpretations of who's a gilgul of whom.

Comment: @user6591 I read the summary and the themes, but I'm not catching on. What sort of story are you imagining might have happened?

Comment: @Harel13 Just a joke. Don't think too hard about it.

Comment: @user6591 oh... :D